# Как в мобильной версии сделать рандомный показ 1 блока из 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

С JS и PhP слишком мало еще знаком, поэтому прошу помощи!

Вот есть media ,например, до 414px , и нужно чтобы при обновлении сайта на моб. такого разрешения cменялся блок. Т.е показывался один из 3, и так рандомно.

Буду очень благодарен!

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
let randomItem = getRandomArbitrary(0, 3)
if (window.innerWidth < 414) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('.music')[randomItem].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.music {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="music">
  <img src="audio1.jpg" width="290px" height="280px" />
  <p>Citizen — Yellow Love</p>
  <audio src="6666.mp3" controls>Citizen — Yellow Love</audio>
</div>
<div class="music">
  <img src="audio22.jpg" width="300px" height="280px" />
  <p>Low Roar- Don't Be So Serious</p>
  <audio src="7777.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
<div class="music">
  <img src="audio3.jpg" width="290px" height="280px" />
  <p>Mo - Mercy</p>
  <audio src="8888.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
```

Где-то явно ошибка:с (скрипте)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return  Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min))
}
let randomItem = getRandomArbitrary(0,2)
  if(window.innerWidth = 414) {
document.getElementsByClassName('music')[randomItem].style.display="block";
}
```